# Spring form -- modelAttribute name as java constant

Tags: java, forms, spring, scriptlet, modelattribute

in order to not repeat myself in code I've used `modelAttribute` name as java constant

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class Controller {
    public static final String MODEL_ATTRIBUTE = "myModel";

    public String renderPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute(MODEL_ATTRIBUTE, ...);
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Now I import this constant into JSP using scriptlet (I know that scriptlets are bad, but I'm not familiar with better solution).

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>

<%@page import="static com.example.Controller.*" %>

<form:form action="/" modelAttribute="<%= MODEL_ATTRIBUTE %>">

    <form:label path="attr1">Attribute:</form:label>
    <form:input path="attr1" />

    <c:forEach items="${???.attr2}" var="item">
        ...    
    </c:forEach>
    <input type="submit" />
</form:form>
```

How should I refer to `modelAttribute` object in the forEach loop? Is there better solution for [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) in Spring forms?

Answer (score 0):

Use the model name,

```
<c:forEach items="${myModel.attributeNameFromYourModel}" var="item">
        ...    
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. The reason I've asked this question is that I don't want to use model name directly. I want to have it stored at single place e.g. java constant which is used across whole application. If I use your approach and I would like to change model name, then I have to change it at least at two different places. This can bring many dumb errors in future.

Comment: @kurochenko I understand your sentiment. But JSPs just don't work that way, unless you use scriptlets, which is evil

Comment: Personally am not a fan of using scriptlet. But what I could suggest here is assign the model attribute name in jsp and refer the assigned value in other places. Eg: <c:set var="newModelName" scope="page"><%= MODEL_ATTRIBUTE %></c:set> But unfortunately it makes it more dirty :(